# Unix Scripting - Division

Tags: bash, unix

I'm building a calculator in the bash shell, but I'm having trouble with division. I've tried adding brackets $(( )) around the entire line and then, only surrounding the two operands, but the total remain incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read user input
echo "Enter operand:"
  read num1
echo "Enter operator:"
  read operator
echo "Enter operand:"
  read num2

case $operator in
        +) total=`echo $num1 + $num2 | bc`;;
        -) total=`echo $num1 - $num2 | bc`;;
        *) total=`echo $num1 *\ $num2 | bc`;;
        /) total=`echo scale=2; $(( $num1 / $num2 )) | bc`;;
esac
echo "Result: $num1 $operator $num2 = $total"
```

Comment: Bash doesn't do floating point numbers. You will need to use `bc` (or another external utility) for everything.

Comment: _It is a common practice to use the wildcard asterisk symbol (*) as a final pattern to define the default case. This pattern will always match._ If you move the multiplication last, division can be reached. Correct way is to escape the asterisk: `\*)`

Comment: @peregrinefalcon : Aside from the error in the `case` statement pointed out by James Brown, you should say in your question for which input you get an incorrect output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote the text in the echo and remove the $(( )).

```
echo "scale=2; $num1 / $num2" | bc
```

In your code you want to assign the result of that to `total` so you still need to run the entire echo command string in a subshell

```
total=$(echo "scale=2; $num1 / $num2" | bc)
```

or the same thing but using backticks

```
total=`echo "scale=2; $num1 / $num2" | bc`
```

Comment: I've made your edit. The line looks like this, and it doesn't work. Did I misunderstand? 

/) total=echo "scale=2; $num1 / $num2" | bc;;